# What is the Standard for Method Location in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Application. I am on the fence. I have a series of methods that call an external library, instantiate a class, and call the methods, (currently defined in the controller for each view).

I reuse the methods across multiple controllers.

I want to make sure that this application stays loosely coupled going forward.

My question is for those who know MVC, what is the accepted standard for MVC?

I see three options:

1. Create a class that contains the methods and Instantiate those methods in each controller. This way I have something in between the individual controllers and the library.

   2. Add the methods to the model that the class inherits and call the methods from the class. However, then all my controllers would be tightly coupled to the model.
   3. Add the methods from the library directly in each controller. I would be tightly coupled to the library but each controller would have it's own private methods I could call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a big topic. But generally you should set things up for [dependency injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Hh323705(v=VS.100).aspx).

Your external library is going to expose certain methods. You should treat that external library as though it can be swapped out at any time. So the general practice is to write a interface that defines all the operations the external library should perform, and your controller should *only* know about that interface. This keeps the controller from needing to know details about the external interface that it doesn't need to know, preventing them from being tightly coupled.

This has several advantages:

- It makes it easy to swap out components quickly, making your site more modular
- It's easier to unit test because you can isolate particular pieces of code and mock the rest

Below is an example. Let's pretend the external library (let's call it `ExternalDataRetriever` is for retrieving certain data from a website.

Controller

```
public class ProductController: Controller
{
    private IDataRetreiever DataRetriever {get; set;}

    public ProductController(IDataRetriever dataRetriever) //this is called Constructor Injection
    {
        DataRetriever = dataRetriever;
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        var data = DataRetriever.GetData();
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

Your `IDataRetriever` is the glue between the site and your bridge.

```
interface IDataRetriever
{
    public DataType GetData();
}
```

This class will serve as the bridge to the external library.

```
public class ExternalDataRetrieverBridge : IDataRetriever
{
    public DataType GetData()
    {
        /* make calls to ExternalDataRetriever here to get the data */
    }
}
```

When you create the controller, the constructor requires an instance of `IDataRetriever`. In your Dependency Injection container (I prefer [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)) you can have it provide an instance of `ExternalDataRetrieverBridge` to the controller constructor to satisfy the dependency on `IDataRetriever`. Here's what the code might look like to configure Ninject to do that:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{           
    kernel.Bind<IDataRetriever>().To<ExternalDataRetrieverBridge>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 

I've used DI in the past for Entity Framework but never for an external library, although I guess you could call Entity Framework an External Library.

Answer (score 2):

The details are quite vague here, so I can't really elaborate too much. What I think should determine the structure is whether the library helps with business logic or controller logic, as it then becomes simple where it should be incorporated.

`business logic:` class wrapper in conjunction with your Model

`controller logic:` class wrapper (or BaseController or similar) in conjunction with your controller logic

I do tend to agree that it is nice to keep the external libraries separated if possible.